# Using Pivot with more than one column using sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have QUERY:

```
 SELECT dept,csedept_name,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December
FROM (SELECT CAST(employeedept AS INT) as dept,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q1,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q2,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q3,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q4,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q5,
count(*) as 'totalstars',month_cse= datename(month,execoffice_date),YEAR_cse =YEAR(execoffice_date)
        FROM CSEReduxResponses
        WHERE 
      execoffice_status = 1 
      and employeedept =17
        group by employeedept,month(execoffice_date),YEAR(execoffice_date),DATENAME(month,execoffice_date)

      ) 
    AS r JOIN CSEReduxDepts d
ON d.csedept_id = r.dept and d.csedept_id=17
PIVOT( SUM(q1)
    FOR [month_cse] IN (
        [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August], [September],[October],[November],[December]
        )) AS pvt
```

Which gets the average in each month depending on the department. 
In the query above im getting the sum for 'q1' and its displaying the correct number for that month and department
but its displaying each month in 1 row and I can only show 'q1' when i would like to show q1-q5.

I may be taking the long/wrong way to do this, maybe using pivot is wrong way to go.

Is there a way i will be able to add the q1-q5 and show on the corresponding month?

I made a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05390/1

Answer (score 0):

How about this query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05390/18)

**Query 1**:

```
;with
years as 
(select distinct year(execoffice_date) y from CSEReduxResponses),
months as 
(select 'January' as m, 1 n
union select 'February', 2 n
union select 'March', 3 n
union select 'April', 4 n
union select 'May', 5 n
union select 'June', 6 n
union select 'July', 7 n
union select 'August', 8 n
union select 'September', 9 n
union select 'October', 10 n
union select 'November', 11 n
union select 'December', 12 n),
cse as (SELECT CAST(employeedept AS INT) as dept,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating1>0 THEN CAST(rating1 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q1,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating2>0 THEN CAST(rating2 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q2,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating3>0 THEN CAST(rating3 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q3,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating4>0 THEN CAST(rating4 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q4,
        ROUND(AVG(case when rating5>0 THEN CAST(rating5 AS FLOAT) ELSE null END), 2) as q5,
        count(*) as 'totalstars', YEAR(execoffice_date) as YEAR_cse, month(execoffice_date) as m_cse
        FROM CSEReduxResponses
        group by employeedept, month(execoffice_date), YEAR(execoffice_date)

      ) 
SELECT csedept_id, d.csedept_name, years.y, months.m, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, totalstars
FROM years cross join months
cross join CSEReduxDepts d
left join cse on
months.n = cse.m_cse and d.csedept_id = cse.dept
where d.csedept_id = 17
order by years.y, months.n, csedept_id, csedept_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05390/18/0)**:

```
| CSEDEPT_ID |  CSEDEPT_NAME |    Y |         M |     Q1 |     Q2 |     Q3 |     Q4 |     Q5 | TOTALSTARS |
|------------|---------------|------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|------------|
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |   January | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |  February | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |     March | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |     April | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |       May |   2.83 |    4.5 |   3.67 |   1.75 |      1 |          6 |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |      June |   2.33 |      4 |   3.33 |      2 |      1 |          3 |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |      July | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |    August | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 | September | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |   October | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |  November | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
|         17 | department 17 | 2014 |  December | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |     (null) |
```

You can even comment the last `where d.csedept_id = 17` clause to retrieve the details for all departments. I do not think that displaying q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, TOTALSTARS in separate columns for every month will be wise. You will end up with 60 columns in this case

Comment: thanks for this solution , what i eventually would like to do is add up all the may q1-q5 and get that average , would that be possible in the query?